# How to create a method inside onCreate() in Android

Tags: java, android

How do I create a method inside `onCreate()` method? When I am creating its showing error:

> Syntax error on token void @ expected

And if method can not be created inside `onCreate()` method than please tell me how do I create a method outside the `onCreate()` and pass `mContext` and `mActivity` from the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote as well as the error logs :)

Comment: You want to create a method inside a method =))

Comment: study the basis of methods in java/android

Comment: **Methods** are created inside **classes**, not **methods**.

Comment: You can **call** a method inside another one. But you can't have **nested** methods.

Comment: you create a method outside the oncreate then call it inside it, you can't declare method inside method that applicable only for class

Comment: If you don't have a book, you might want to go through this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Comment: After you go through the java tutorial, go through the android tutorial (make sure to do the java tutorial first): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Declare a class variable to use in this class
public <data-type> mContext;
public <data-type> mActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = <Your value>;
        mActivity = <Your value>;

        myMethod (mContext , mActivity);

}
private void myMethod (<data-type> mContext, <data-type> mActivity) {
   /*
    Your Code Goes Here
  */
}
}
```

*Note that tags like  should be replaced by actual types without inequality signs, such as "int" and "short".

Comment: Marked as answer

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    yourmethod();
}

public void yourmethod(){
// your code here
}

}
```

Comment: @saurabh gupta answer is correct... you have to pass mContext and mActivity to your function and Declare a class variable to use in this class
... But much thanks for your efforts... I always appreciate peoples efforts... Good try...

Comment: you can use **this** if the activity is the same